# Plot 3 sets of data on 2 axes

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, oxyplot

I have a user's blood pressure data and would like to plot this using Oxyplot. There's the systolic value,diastolic value and the date representing the date the tests were taken.

I'm a little stuck on how to represent the 2 values for the blood pressure in one data point, against the month variable since a data point only takes 2 variables.

Here's my code:

```
 plotModel = new PlotModel { Title = "Blood Presure" };
 plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left,AbsoluteMaximum = 190, Maximum = 190,AbsoluteMinimum = 10, Minimum = 10, Title = "Diastolic" });
 plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,AbsoluteMaximum = 12, Maximum = 12,AbsoluteMinimum = 1, Minimum = 1, MajorStep = 1, Title = "Month" });
 plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Top, AbsoluteMaximum = 190, Maximum = 190, AbsoluteMinimum = 10, Minimum = 10, Title = "Systolic" });

var series2 = new LineSeries
{
    MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
    MarkerSize = 4,
    MarkerStroke = OxyColors.White

};

if (userInfo != null)
    {
        if (userInfo.Count > 0)
        {
            var counter = 0.00;

            foreach (Info healthData in userInfo)
                {
                    var bp = healthData.BloodPressure;

                    var date = healthData.CreatedDate;

                    var month = date.Month;

                    if (dateLabel != null)
                    {
                        dateLabel.Text = month.ToString();

                    }

                        // TODO Split this blood pressure value

                    var result = Regex.Split(bp,"/");

                    string systolicValue = null;
                    string diastolicValue = null;

                    if (result.Length > 1)
                    {
                        systolicValue = result[0];
                        diastolicValue = result[1];
                    }


                    series2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(month + counter, double.Parse(systolicValue)));

                    counter += 0.02;

                    }
```

How can I best represent these values on a graph?
Here's a screen shot from my graph currently :

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simpler solution capturing all the three sets of data by using `PointAnnotations` like this:

```
plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left,AbsoluteMaximum = 190, Maximum = 190,AbsoluteMinimum = 70, Minimum = 70, Title = "Systolic" });
plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, AbsoluteMaximum = 190, Maximum = 190, AbsoluteMinimum = 40, Minimum = 40, Title = "Diastolic" });

var series2 = new LineSeries
{
MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
MarkerSize = 4,
MarkerStroke = OxyColors.White

;

if (userInfo != null)
{
    if (userInfo.Count > 0)
    {
        var counter = 0.00;

        foreach (Info healthData in userInfo)
            {
                var bp = healthData.BloodPressure;

                var date = healthData.CreatedDate;

                var month = date.Month;

                if (dateLabel != null)
                {
                    dateLabel.Text = month.ToString();

                }

                    // TODO Split this blood pressure value

                var result = Regex.Split(bp,"/");

                string systolicValue = null;
                string diastolicValue = null;

                if (result.Length > 1)
                {
                    systolicValue = result[0];
                    diastolicValue = result[1];
                }


                series2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(double.Parse(diastolicValue), double.Parse(systolicValue)));

                var pointAnnotation1 = new PointAnnotation();  
                pointAnnotation1.X = Convert.ToDouble(diastolicValue);
                pointAnnotation1.Y = Convert.ToDouble(systolicValue);
                pointAnnotation1.Text = String.Format("{0}",date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")); // I'm adding the date label here
                plotModel.Annotations.Add(pointAnnotation1);


               }

             }

        }

    plotModel.Series.Add(series2);
```

Below is an image of what the graph now looks like

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

Your data is three dimensional. You can represent them on a 3D graph (which as long as I know OxyPlot does not support). Another option is to draw a scatter plot and show one of the dimensions as the size (and/or color) of the points:

```
        //Data:
        int n = 10;
        var dia = new double[10] {1,3,3,4,4,2,4,5,6,4 };
        var sys = new double[10] {2,2,2,4,5,3,4,4,5,6 };
        var mon = Enumerable.Range(1, n).ToArray(); 

        var model = new PlotModel { Title = "ScatterSeries" };
        var scatterSeries = new OxyPlot.Series.ScatterSeries { MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle };
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            var x = mon[i];
            var y = sys[i];
            var size = dia[i];
            scatterSeries.Points.Add(new OxyPlot.Series.ScatterPoint(x, y, size, size));
        } 
        model.Series.Add(scatterSeries);
        model.Axes.Add(new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearColorAxis { Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Right, Palette = OxyPalettes.BlueWhiteRed(30) });
        model.Axes.Add(new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis { Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Bottom });
        model.Axes.Add(new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis { Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Left });
        var plot = new OxyPlot.Wpf.PlotView() { Model = model };
        this.Content = plot;
```

Comment: Ramin, thank you. I'll try this approach and share my feedback with you.

Comment: Is this line entirely correct? scatterSeries.Points.Add(new OxyPlot.Series.ScatterPoint(x, y, size, size));  I don't think we capture all the 3 variables in the ScatterPoint. You only assign the x and y , but pass the diastolic value as the size.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't know about the bubble chart. So in that case, can I use the systolic and diastolic values for the x and y variables, then use the month for the size?

Comment: why not. however, I would prefer time on horizontal axis, since it increases monotonically

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback @Ron. I'm accepting your answer. I also found another approach, which is what I ended up using. The bubble chart works but users had a hard time telling the exact month those results were taken. So I had to append text (the dates) against the dots.